# Update App React Native 32 Bits to 64 Bits

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have an outdated 32-bit application to react native, now I want to update that application with the latest versions, my question is, I have to work on that application or I can create a new one with the same package name and the same keystore, in such a way that it helps me to update the previous one, I hope you have explained, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to upgrade a react native app from 0.49 to the latest, 0.61. There's some tools available, `react-native upgrade` and `react-native-git-upgrade`, but I had little luck with either one.

For me the easiest way was performing the update on the current codebase, with the help of RN diff purge: [react-native-community/rn-diff-purge](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge)

From their *README.md* :

> This repository exposes an untouched React Native app generated with the CLI npx >react-native init RnDiffApp. Each new React Native release causes a new project to >be created, removing the old one, and getting a diff between them. This way, the >diff is always clean, always in sync with the changes of the init template.

For whichever version you're currently at, you can look up the *diff* of a clean project in that version to whichever other version you'd like to upgrade to. You can check all the changes that happened between those two versions, and apply them to you own project. When I upgraded, I just applied the changes in [rn-diff-purge/compare/release0.49.1..release/0.61.5](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/release/0.49.1..release/0.61.5) to my project.

Some things to conider:

If you **only** need to upgrade react native to be able to get 64 bit builds, it's going to be way less work to update to 0.59 (first version to support 64bit), than to upgrade to 0.60 or later. On version 0.60 they introduced auto-linking, meaning that you no longer need to run `react-native link` after installing a native dependency, but you'll need to unlink all of your current native dependencies if you don't want to see some "duplicate dependency" errors.

If you do decide to upgrade to 0.60 or later, and you have some dependency that you don't want to unlink (maybe you've added `react-native-code-push`, and you set the deploymentKey when you initialize the package in your `MainApplication.java`), you need to add them to the file `react-native.config.js` (if you don't have one, you should create one at the root of your project). The file should look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-code-push': {
      platforms: {
        android: null, // disable Android platform, other platforms will still autolink if provided
      },
    },
  },
};
```

That's all, good luck!